# ThreadLocal initialValue() vs set()

Tags: java

I understand the purpose of `ThreadLocal` class; but bit baffled by the methods `initialValue()` and `set()`.
To me, both seems to be having the same purpose - to set the value to the `ThreadLocal` object so that each thread will get its own copy.

Regardless of whether `initialValue()` or `set()` is used to set the value, you always get the value by calling the `get()` method.

You can remove the value by calling the `remove()` method.

1. When do we need to use the `initialValue()` method?
2. When do we need to use the `set()` method?

Comment: You would use `initialValue()` when you want the `ThreadLocal` to have an _initial value_. That's the value the `ThreadLocal` has _before the first `set`_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `initValue()` is a `protected` method, which means you can not *use* it outside the `ThreadLocal` class or it's children. It serves one purpose only, which it's name suggests, to provide initial value and is invoked only once.

If you look at the class, you'll find that internally, `initValue()` always returns `null` unless you provide a `Supplier` with `ThreadLocal.withInitial(Supplier supplier)` or override this method in your own extension of `ThreadLocal`.

Do read the docs for details. They always help-

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html

Hope this helps! Happy coding.

Comment: Definitely helpful! Thanks very much.